# How to save in div content as image (png, jpg ...) in jsf or primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, html5-canvas

I am doing a project for school. Subject of project is tshirt design. I am using jsf and primefaces. But I don't know well jsf and primefaces.
I have a problem. In a div, a design is done, then I wanted to save in div content as image file. Can I do with using HTML5? How do I add html5 to JSF project? How do I process?

Comment: You can use canvas element for this. an can get the data as base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a canvas with wanted size, load your graphics stuff in the canvas and then use the canvas.toDataURL(fileType) to get the file content as base64, here is the link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't know how to add html5 to jsf.